# python file writing then appending

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function where it I write content to a text file, then i copy the contents of another text file all to the same 1 line. Then The next time i run this function i want it to keep the content only creating a new line then populating that line.

So far i have

```
def write_to_new():
    report = 'original.txt'
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    new_file = open('refresh.txt', 'a')
    new_file.write('Year: %s' % now.year+', ' + 'Month: %s' % now.month+', ' + 'Day: %s' % now.day+', ')
    new_file.write(shutil.copy(report,'refresh.txt'))
```

When i run this it gives me an

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues with `shutil`:

- `shutil.copy()` in Py2 doesn't return anything - the cause of the error (in Py3 it returns the name of the file created)
- `shutil.copy()` uses the underlying shell to copy the file to a new file, and doesn't bring the contents of that file into python

Just open the `original.txt` and read the contents and write it out:

```
def write_to_new():
    with open('original.txt') as report, open('refrest.txt', 'a') as new_file:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        new_file.write('Year: {now.year}, '
                       'Month: {now.month}, '
                       'Day: {now.day}, {original}'
                       .format(now=now, original=report.read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do:

```
new_file.write(shutil.copy(report,'refresh.txt'))
```

`new_file.write` needs a string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Before you write the content to new_file you have to convert the copied content to type string.

new_file.write(str(shutil.copy(report,'refresh.txt')))

Hope it'll work